# Android MVP + Google Dagger 2 + SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, dagger-2

I am working on a school project where I have to code an android project in MVP architectural pattern. I started doing a bit of research on Google Dagger 2 as well. For now I am simply trying to check if a user exists in the database or not. The problem, as everyone knows is passing the context. I looked for a concise answer but I couldn't find anything. This is how I tried to do it.

Code for using Dagger 2 for context:

```
public class DaggerApplication extends Application {
    DaggerComponent daggerComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        daggerComponent = DaggerComponent.builder().daggerModule(new DaggerModule(this)).build();
        daggerComponent.inject(this);
    }

    public DaggerComponent getAppComponent(){
        return daggerComponent;
    }
}


@Module
public class DaggerModule {
    private final DaggerApplication daggerApplication;

    public DaggerModule(DaggerApplication daggerApplication){
        this.daggerApplication = daggerApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context providesApplicationContext() {
        return this.daggerApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("My_Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component
        (modules = {DaggerModule.class})
public interface DaggerComponent {
    void inject(DaggerApplication daggerApplication);
    void inject(SigninActivityFragment signinActivityFragment);
}
```

I then get my context in the fragment like this:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ((DaggerApplication)getActivity().getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this);
        accountPresenter = new AccountPresenter(this,new MyDatabaseSource(context));
    }
```

The MyDatabaseSource needs this context for the database to work. Then this MyDatabaseSource opens the database gets the user from the database and closes it. Something like this:

```
public class MyDatabaseSource implements MyModel {
    public MyDatabaseSource(@NonNull Context context) {
        checkNotNull(context);
        myLocalDatabaseOpenHelper = new MyLocalDatabaseOpenHelper(context);
    }
    //Implementing MyModel functions here
}
```

This is why I need the context.

```
public class MyLocalDatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String MY_LOCAL_DATABASE_NAME = "MyUserDatabase";
    private static final int MY_LOCAL_DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyLocalDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, MY_LOCAL_DATABASE_NAME, null, MY_LOCAL_DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Created my database here

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Not required as at version 1
    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Not required as at version 1
    }
}
```

I created the interface that MyDatabaseSource implements and I called it MyModel.

Here is the code:

```
public interface MyModel {

    void insertUser(User user);
    void deleteUser(int index);
    void updateUser(User user);
    ArrayList <User> getUsers();
    User getUser(int index);

}
```

Then my presenter has everything it needs in-order to become the middle man between my view and model.

This is my presenter code:

```
public AccountPresenter(AccountView accountView, MyModel myModel) {
        this.accountView = accountView;
        this.myModel = myModel;
    }

    public void onSignInButtonClicked() {
        String username = accountView.getUsername();
        String password = accountView.getPassword();
        if (username.isEmpty()) {
            accountView.setUsernameErrorMessage(R.string.activity_signin_username_error);
        }
        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            accountView.setPasswordErrorMessage(R.string.activity_signin_password_error);
        }

        ArrayList<User> userArrayList = myModel.getUsers();
        if (userArrayList.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < userArrayList.size(); i++) {
                if (username.equals(userArrayList.get(i).getUserName())) {
                    if (password.equals(userArrayList.get(i).getUserPassword())) {
                        accountView.showUserExists(R.string.activity_signin_user_exists_toast);
                    } else {
                        accountView.showIncorrectPassword(R.string.activity_signin_incorrect_password_toast);
                    }
                } else {
                    accountView.showUserDoesNotExist(R.string.activity_signin_user_does_not_exist_toast);
                }
            }
        } else {
            accountView.showNoUserExists(R.string.activity_signin_no_exists_toast);
        }
    }
```

I would like to know if this is the correct way of implementing MVP using Google Dagger 2. I personally feel like there should be another way to implement this; passing context to the presenter beats the purpose of using Google Dagger. I just started researching on Google Dagger 2 and MVP pattern. So any suggestions will be helpful. I just want it to be right. Don't want to loose a grade. :)

Any suggestions and advice will be helpful. :)

Comment: you may find this article useful [Why Activities in Android are not UI Elements](http://www.techyourchance.com/activities-android/)

Answer (score 1):

> passing context to the presenter beats the purpose of using Google Dagger

If Android apps had a single entry point (like a `main(String [] args)` method) then it would be possible and desirable to inject all dependencies, including Context, using Dagger alone. In other words, you wouldn't have to have this system where a Dagger Component is initialized with a Context as a parameter. If this was the case then passing a Context to the presenter would, in some way, beat the purpose of using Dagger 2.

However, the instances of Application and Activity that constitute an app are not able to be instantiated directly. Although some of these classes may have public constructors, you cannot obtain a fully-functional instance through instantiation. Instead, these classes are instantiated are supplied with a Context and other dependencies (such as a FragmentManager) by the system.

Likewise, having the Context from the Application or Activity as a dependency for the repository/data or model is not a preventable violation separation of concerns between model and view.

> I would like to know if this is the correct way of implementing MVP using Google Dagger 2

For this I think you will have to compare what you have done with other sample MVP projects. Here is the [official one from Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger/)

Also, you will have to decide if you have really fulfilled the three salient features of [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter):

> 1. The model is an interface defining the data to be displayed or otherwise acted upon in the user interface.
> 2. The presenter acts upon the model and the view. It retrieves data from repositories (the model), and formats it for display in the view.
> 3. The view is a passive interface that displays data (the model) and routes user commands (events) to the presenter to act upon that data.

Rather than worrying about whether you have the 'correct solution' for MVP in Android, I think the most important thing is for you yourself to be able to understand and justify how your app fulfills the criteria of MVP and achieves separation of concerns within in the constraints of the Android architecture.